# How to extract the logic part from map function to other self created functions. Keeping the map() logic into separate part

Tags: reactjs

"As in this i have to separate logic from map() and put it into a function and then call it"

```
<tbody>
      {studentDatas.map((data) => {
        if (
          data.hindi < 35 ||
          data.english < 35 ||
          data.math < 35 ||
          data.science < 35
        ) {
          return (
            <tr key={data.id}>
              <td>{data.id}</td>
              <td>{data.name}</td>
              <td>{data.hindi}</td>
              <td>{data.english}</td>
              <td>{data.math}</td>
              <td>{data.science}</td>
              <td>Need to study more</td>
              <td>Fail</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }
        if (data.hindi + data.english + data.math + data.science < 250) {
          return (
            <tr key={data.id}>
              <td>{data.id}</td>
              <td>{data.name}</td>
              <td>{data.hindi}</td>
              <td>{data.english}</td>
              <td>{data.math}</td>
              <td>{data.science}</td>
              <td>Need to work hard</td>
              <td>Pass</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }
        if (data.hindi + data.english + data.math + data.science < 300) {
          return (
            <tr key={data.id}>
              <td>{data.id}</td>
              <td>{data.name}</td>
              <td>{data.hindi}</td>
              <td>{data.english}</td>
              <td>{data.math}</td>
              <td>{data.science}</td>
              <td>Good</td>
              <td>Pass</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }
        if (data.hindi + data.english + data.math + data.science <= 400) {
          return (
            <tr key={data.id}>
              <td>{data.id}</td>
              <td>{data.name}</td>
              <td>{data.hindi}</td>
              <td>{data.english}</td>
              <td>{data.math}</td>
              <td>{data.science}</td>
              <td>Excellent</td>
              <td>Pass</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }
      })}
    </tbody>
```

"JSON DATA"
export const studentDatas = [
{
id: 1,
name: "Student1",
hindi: 10,
english: 10,
math: 20,
science: 25,
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Student2",
hindi: 40,
english: 80,
math: 0,
science: 0,
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Student3",
hindi: 70,
english: 80,
math: 80,
science: 90,
},
{
id: 4,
name: "Student4",
hindi: 20,
english: 45,
math: 50,
science: 70,
},
{
id: 5,
name: "Student5",
hindi: 40,
english: 50,
math: 70,
science: 90,
},
{
id: 6,
name: "Student6",
hindi: 28,
english: 70,
math: 80,
science: 10,
},
{
id: 7,
name: "Student7",
hindi: 16,
english: 50,
math: 50,
science: 10,
},
{
id: 8,
name: "Student8",
hindi: 78,
english: 50,
math: 50,
science: 50,
},
{
id: 9,
name: "Student9",
hindi: 100,
english: 100,
math: 100,
science: 100,
},
];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   const getTotalMarks = (data) => {
    return data.hindi + data.english + data.math + data.science;
  }
```

and in map loop

```
<tbody>
    {studentDatas.map((data) => {
      const isFail = data.hindi < 35 || data.english < 35 || data.math < 35 || data.science < 35;
      const total = !isFail && getTotalMarks(data);
      return (
        <tr key={data.id}>
          <td>{data.id}</td>
          <td>{data.name}</td>
          <td>{data.hindi}</td>
          <td>{data.english}</td>
          <td>{data.math}</td>
          <td>{data.science}</td>
          {
            isFail ?
              <>
                <td>Need to study more</td>
                <td>Fail</td>
              </>
              : <>
                {
                  total < 250 ? <td>Need to study more</td>
                    : total < 300 ? <td>Good</td> : <td>Excellent</td>
                }
                <td>Fail</td>
              </>
          }
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
```